# Why xroot.iter() can print XPath, but can't return as list of XPath's in Python?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

My XML file:

```
<root xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/"
xmlns:f="https://www.w3schools.com/furniture">

<h:table>
  <h:tr>
    <h:td>Apples</h:td>
    <h:td>Bananas</h:td>
  </h:tr>
</h:table>

<f:table>
  <f:name>African Coffee Table</f:name>
  <f:width>80</f:width>
  <f:length>120</f:length>
</f:table>

</root>
```

The following code output does only return an xmlns link.

```
def loopGroup(xml_file,df_cols):

    ndf=pd.DataFrame()
    xtree = et.parse(xml_file)
    xroot = xtree.getroot()
    out_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_cols)

    for node in xroot.iter():
        data=node.tag,node.attrib
        return data
```

However, if I change to code below:

```
for node in xroot.iter():
    data=node.tag,node.attrib
    print(data)
```

It will print out like following (my expected output):

```
    ('root', {})
('{http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/}table', {})
('{http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/}tr', {})
('{http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/}td', {})
```

How do I put these expected output above convert to csv?

Comment: What's your XML input? (To complete a [mcve]).

Comment: I update my xml file already,please take a look.

Comment: Nope, it is column name variable, or u can delete it directly.

Comment: Nope, it is column name variable or u can delete it directly.